# Keep only desired characters and separate with semicolon in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, string

The problem:

I have text data imported into the db with a lot of unwanted characters. I need to keep only 4 capital letter strings within the imported text string. Example:

```
1447;#MIBD (This is a nice name);#2056;#LKRE (Very nice name indeed)
```

this could be in one column in one row of my table. What I need to extract from the string is:

```
MIBD and LKRE
```

And the result should preferably be the desired strings separated with semicolons.

It should be applied to the whole column and I cannot know how many of these 4 upper case letter strings might appear in one row.

Went through all sorts of function like PATINDEX etc. but really do not know how to approach it. thanks for any help!

Comment: what are the rules ? is it always 4 upper case characters ?

Comment: Yes, always 4 upper case characters.

Comment: Is there always are space following the 4 capitals? And a semicolong preceding them?

Comment: there is always a space after the 4 chars and there is always a # right before. the semicolon is also always before the #

Answer (score 0):

try this, it assumes that the four char code is always preceded by ;# . As PATINDEX is case insensitive I have added additional check to verify that all the four character are capital.

```
DECLARE @MyTable Table( ID INT, MyString VARCHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
     (1, '1447;#MIBD (This is a nice name);#2056;#LKRE (Very nice name indeed)')
    ,(2, ';#DBCC (This is a nice name);#2056;#LLC (Very nice name indeed) ;#ABCD')
    ,(3, ';#AaaA;#OPQR;1234 (and) ;#WXYZ')
    ,(4, ';#abc this empty string without any code')

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT ID 
        ,SUBSTRING(MyString, PATINDEX('%;#[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%',MyString)+2, 4) AS NewString
        ,STUFF(MyString, 1, PATINDEX('%;#[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%',MyString)+6, '') AS MyString
    FROM @MyTable m
    WHERE PATINDEX('%;#[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%',MyString) > 0

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ID 
        ,SUBSTRING(MyString, PATINDEX('%;#[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%',MyString)+2, 4) AS NewString
        ,STUFF(MyString, 1, PATINDEX('%;#[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%',MyString)+6, '') AS MyString
    FROM CTE c
    WHERE PATINDEX('%;#[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%',MyString) > 0     
) 

SELECT c.ID,
    STUFF(( SELECT '; ' + NewString
            FROM CTE c1
            WHERE c1.ID = c.ID
                AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(NewString, 1, 1)) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z')  -- first char
                AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(NewString, 2, 1)) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z')  -- second char 
                AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(NewString, 3, 1)) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z')  -- third char 
                AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(NewString, 4, 1)) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z')  -- fourth char 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')      -- use the value clause to hanlde xml character issue like, &,",>,<
        ,1,1,'') AS CodeList
FROM CTE c
GROUP BY ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

I came to something like this so far:

```
ALTER FUNCTION CleanData
(
    -- Parameters here
    @Text AS VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)

AS
BEGIN

WHILE PATINDEX('%[0-9#;()]%', @Text) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Text = STUFF(@Text, PATINDEX('%[0-9#;()]%', @Text), 1, '') 
END
RETURN @Text

END
```

But what I get is the Initials and the characters in parantheses as the PATINDEX cannot differ between the upper and lower case. Maybe it might be helpful for somebody else